# tikzmark with equation, subsequent text got overlapped

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

I am trying to use `tikzmark` library to annotate equations. I have the following MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\[
    \text{Regret}_T = \tikzmarknode{a}{T \cdot {\mu^*}} - \tikzmarknode{b}{\sum_{t=0}^{T-1} \mu_{a_t}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[red,thick,->] (a.south) to [in=90,out=245] +(190:3.0cm) node[anchor=north,text=red, align = center] {total expected reward \\ if pull best arm over $T$ rounds};
    \draw[blue,thick,->] (b.south) to [in=90,out=245] +(360:3.0cm) node[anchor=north,text=blue, align = center] {total expected reward \\ of our selected arms};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

And this line of text is overlapped. % NOTE THIS
\end{document}
```

which produces this
[image]

Note that the subsequent text got overlapped, which I believe is due to `overlay` option of `tikzpicture` environment. Other than manually inserting empty lines, I wonder if there is some automatic way to make latex aware of these arrows and arrange the layout so that the line below can render correctly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, positioning}
\begin{document}
\[
\text{Regret}_T = \tikzmarknode{a}{T \cdot {\mu^*}} - \tikzmarknode{b}{\sum_{t=0}^{T-1} \mu_{a_t}}
\]
\begin{center}
\tikzmarknode[text=red, align=center]{aa}{total expected reward\\if pull best arm over $T$ rounds}
\qquad
\tikzmarknode[text=blue, align=center]{bb}{total expected reward\\of our selected arms}
\end{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red, thick, ->, shorten <= 4pt] (a) to[out=250, in=90] (aa);
\draw[blue, thick,->, shorten <=-2pt] (b) to[out=320, in=90] (bb);
\end{tikzpicture}
And this line of text is not overlapped.
\end{document}
```

[image: Formula with arrows to colored text]

Comment: Thanks! This looks great!